# how to step into system.web.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

Does anyone have know how I can step into system.web.mvc? I am getting an error (Cannot create an abstract class) that is buried in the System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel method, and I can't tell which part of my code is causing the issue.

I was advised that I could download the sourcecode from codeplex, (actually microsoft.com/downloads as I am using 1.0), build in Debug and then step through.  I tried, unfortunately the system.web.mvc was installed in GAC, thus causing an ambiguous call, and gacutil would not allow me to uninstall, so tried by hand removing from the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Global\system.web.mvc).  when I ran my program it was still reporting an ambiguous call.

#### Background

A couple of weeks ago I had a problem where MVC was throwing up a YSOD, but I could not step into the code to find the problem because the issue was I was doing something wrong, that was not being picked up until it was in the framework (in this case, by thrashing around blindly for a day I found it was that I didn't have a default empty constructor on one of the classes within my viewmodel).  Now I am getting a different error (Cannot create an abstract class) that is buried in the System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel method, but I don't know what part of my code is causing the error in the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little involved, but you can do it. [Steve Sanderson has step-by-step instructions](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! ... This solved my issue, now stepping into the framework ... now all that is left to do is find that darn bug.

Comment: This blog [has moved](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/).

Comment: For posterity, the gist of the blog is: 1) Download the sources for [MVC 2012](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) (or [MVC5](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) or [6+](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)), 2) Add the project to your existing solution, and 3) Change the reference to System.Web.Mvc to point to your local copy. 4) Remove  from `web.config` the GAC version of MVC, so razor views don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code then you can recompile the code using a different assembily name and reference that.

Comment: i tried that, changing all references to System.Web.Mvcx, tried to re-run got the error: 

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "System.Web.Mvcx.Resources.MvcResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "System.Web.Mvc" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

any ideas what I can do to fix that?