# How to step into MVC4 source code without building assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there an easy way to step through the MVC 4 source from within my solution?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914226/how-to-step-into-system-web-mvc) but the solution requires building the MVC 4 assembly from source. I would think a symbol look up from a server would be preferable but have not been able to make this happen.

Ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the following symbol servers to your Visual Studio and you are good to go:

- http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet
- http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Here's how mine look like:

[image: Options Dialog with Symbols Configured]

Also you need to configure your debugger to use them:

1. Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General.
2. Uncheck "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)"
3. Check "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"
4. Check "Enable source server support"
5. Uncheck "Require source files to exactly match the original version"

Oh and of course don't forget to revert those settings back when you no longer need to debug in .NET sources or otherwise debugging might become a painfully slow experience for you.

Comment: Yeah, they've recently published the ASP.NET MVC 4 RTM PDBs at this location. I've mentioned the others for completeness sake.

Comment: Did you mean Check in step 3?

Comment: It's also possible that the assembly in the GAC will prevent this from working. The easiest way to resolve this, especially on a temporary basis, is to navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\[Version] and rename System.Web.Mvc.dll. .NET will then fall back to the reference in your build directory and things should work.

Comment: This [didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337092/cannot-step-into-mvc4-methods).