# How to debug html.editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view that contains a

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Regions, "_Regions")
```

my problem is that the _Regions.cshtml partial isn't called in at all, I have a breakpoint but that is never reached and it's content never shown. is there anyone who know how I can debug and see where it is failing.

It was my understanding that the  `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Regions, "_Regions")` will be called as soon as I reach it but as just a test I deleted the _Regions.cshtml from my views folder and nothing happened no error nothing at all, doing the same with a @Html.Partial, then I get an error, Am I missing something here?

When I replace the Editorfor, with the partial, then I get into the partial but was just wondering how can I use Editorfor with passing in a model.

Regards

ANSWER:

The view should be in the EditorTemplates folder, alongside all the partial that you will be returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug internal MVC code you need to setup symbol server in your visual studio. 
There is already a tutorial on StackOverflow [How to step into MVC4 source code without building assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609891/how-to-step-into-mvc4-source-code-without-building-assembly)