# How to Fix, Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have the source of System.Web.Mvc assembly. Building is fine. But at runtime it throws,

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. 
>       Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered
>       with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key.
>       (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

How can I debug it? I am using windows 7.

Comment: Where did you reference System.Web.Mvc from?

Comment: In my sample project.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, Actually I want to to debug MVC

Comment: But why did you build your own version of System.Web.Mvc??? Don't do that.

Comment: Why not, that's the point of open source, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to debug the ASP.NET MVC source code and have built your own version of the System.Web.Mvc assembly. The problem with this approach is that you cannot sign it with the official keys. This means that any third party component that you might be using and which depends on System.Web.Mvc should also be recompiled against your own version. Take for example Razor. It also depends on System.Web.Mvc. Did you recompile that as well?

Personally I find it extremely difficult to be building your own version of System.Web.Mvc. In  practice I debug the source code by using the publicly available PDB symbols. So I would advice you NOT to be compiling your own version but work with the official one. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610108/29407

Comment: But in older versions it was very trivial, http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/

Comment: Have tried bypassTrustedAppStrongNames and AllowStrongNameBypass. But nothing happens. Where is this verification triggered?

Comment: Yes, in older versions there weren't so many dependencies on System.Web.Mvc. Those bypasses won't work. Nothing you could do, unless you recompile absolutely every single assembly that you are using in your project and that depends on System.Web.Mvc. But I have already expressed my personal opinion about that in my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Using .NET Source Stepping doesn't work for me - the debugging experience is very poor: I cannot see some local variables and stepping into some functions (all within the System.Web.Mvc assembly) just doesn't work because they're optimized-away - and other issues. I have similar problems with RedGate's Reflector VS extension too - so rebuilding from source is my only option.

Answer (score 7):

Just resolved the same problem:

- build solution with asp.net source code (mine is called 'Runtime.sln')
- unload tests folder from it
- open properties of ***System***.Web.Mvc project
- uncheck Sign on Signing tab
- try to rebuild solution
- uncheck Sign on Signing tab for each failed project

I also removed strong name details from InternalsVisibleTo attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs but it might needed only if you want to build test projects as well.

After that I added System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.WebPages.Deployment and System.Web.WebPages projects as existing projects to my new solution and now I can debug their source code.

Comment: Unchecking the "Sign the assembly" on the Signing tab on the properties of each problematic project solved my problem.

Comment: Worked for trying to use a self-built EntityFramework DLL.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this before and removing the reference to System.Web.Mvc and re-adding it worked.

I also did a clean and re-build which worked.

Hope that helps

Comment: I need to debug MVC source

Comment: Ah sorry I miss read the question. I agree with @DarinDimitrov, you shouldn't have any reason to create your own version of Mvc. What is it your actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

In the AssemblyInfo.cs file there will be a line 
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyDelaySign(true)], if this is removed the GAC issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I tried profiling my application using Visual studio performance profiler and got this error for third party assembly. I did a clean and re-build solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your config file: < hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" / >