# How to navigate/step into asp.net mvc 5 source code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I was following [this post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/). So far I can navigate and build the solution; but whenever I try to debug/run it, I keep this error coming up:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)*

Contrary to the suggestion in the post, I could not find the `assemblies` section inside the `compilation` section of my *web.config* (project root). It looks like this:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Any idea how can I run/debug it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212035/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-st

Comment: hmm, problematic. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

That article is from 2009. I'm not sure what the situation was then, but including the MVC source in your project just to get source debugging for MVC is not necessary. The MVC Nuget package has an associated symbols package on SymbolsSource, which should be included for debugging by default. And, you certainly don't want to create your own custom version of MVC unless you want to *maintain* that fork indefinitely, including applying security patches and such as they arrive (Hint: you don't).

Comment: I am learning MVC. I think navigating and debug stepping can help me learn/explore better. Up to MVC4 it was simple. ... I saw answers about _symbolssource_, but I need to navigate too (without debugging).