# Cannot debug .NET source files in MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I have followed the following guide to try to debug .NET code: [How to step into MVC4 source code without building assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609891/how-to-step-into-mvc4-source-code-without-building-assembly)

I have also enabled Native Code debugging in MVC project.

However, when I try to step into a.NET code, source file is missing not allowing me to debug.

For example, when trying to step into Html.HiddenFor method, it cannot find rttype.cs file, or when trying to step into DateTime object, it cannot find datetime.cs file.

All source code files are being searched in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system.... path that does not obviously exist in my PC.

Any help, please?