# Cannot step into MVC4 methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, debugging

I've followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610108/178757) to try and step into an MVC4 method (`System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action`) and it still won't work; when I debug my controller action and hit F11 on the line that calls `Action()`, it doesn't step into it, it just silently steps over with no popup or anything:

```
  var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
  var myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
* return urlHelper.Action(actionName, "Room", new { companyId = myGuid });
```

During the initial site loading, in the output Debug window, I get:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-1-131760323543445359): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jez\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55b8e42d\c314116e\assembly\dl3\8aef13b9\0036c3f9_8675cd01\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

So it looks like the reason it can't step into MVC4 code is that it can't open the PDB file for my version of MVC4.  If I F12 into the method I want to debug, the metadata shows:

```
#region Assembly System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Development\close.global-core\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll
#endregion
```

As I have followed the steps in the answer I linked, I already have these URLs setup in my symbol server Symbols locations:

- http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet
- http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

So I can't understand why it doesn't get the PDB file - shouldn't these allow me to debug MVC4 methods?

Comment: The pdb files contain only information about classes, methods, variables, source file names and line numbers etc but not the source code. You can’t jump into the method without the actual source and pdb file

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen But it doesn't even popup a window prompting me for the source code file, shouldn't it do that when I hit F11?

Comment: It should if it recognizes the pdb, as far as I know. Why it doesn’t, or how to make it do that, I can’t unfortunately say :/

Comment: As I said the debug window says it can't find or load the PDB.  Are the MVC4 PDBs no longer available at `symbolsource.org` or something?